# knockout subscribe and data-bind error: how to data-bind when also subscribing

Tags: knockout.js

When setting up the view model in the following manner, what is the proper way to declare the data-bind in the markup?

```
var Info;  // global
function initInfo() {
    Info = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.tag = ko.observable(null);       
        self.blurb = ko.observable(null);

        self.tag.subscribe(function (newValue) {            
           alert(newValue);
       });

    };   
}
```

I invoke the binding so:

```
   ko.applyBindings(Info, document.getElementById("tag"));
```

I am getting this error in the console: `ReferenceError: tag is not defined` with this markup:

```
   <input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" data-bind="value:tag" />
```

But if I set up the Info view model as an object as below, there's no such problem, and the binding succeds:

```
 var Info = {

       tag: ko.observable(null)
       .
       .
       .


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Info** is function, not an object. You need to invoke 'new Info()' as pass the resulting object to applyBindings.